# Convert JSON query conditions to MongoDB/Mongoose operations

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am building an application in Angular 8 on the client side and NodeJS 12 with MongoDB 4 / Mongoose 5 on the server side.

I have a query generated by the [Angular query builder module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-query-builder) in JSON format. The JSON object will be sent to the backend via a POST request.

**Question:** How can the JSON query be converted into MongoDB operators to perform the database query?

Here's an example of a simple query generated by the Query Builder plugin. Note the requirement for *multiple levels* of "nested" AND / OR conditions.

```
{
  "condition": "and",
  "rules": [
    {
      "field": "Brief_D_Reactiedatum",
      "operator": "!=",
      "value": "Eventtoets_Fn"
    },
    {
      "condition": "or",
      "rules": [
        {
          "field": "Alleen_AO",
          "operator": "=",
          "value": "Parkeerreden"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to build MongoDB's [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) which is similar to the query that you're getting from **Angular query builder module**. Since the ruleSets can be nested you need to run your mapping function recursively. Below code probably doesn't cover every possible case but should give you a good introduction to get started with such mapping.

```js
let q = {
  "condition": "and",
  "rules": [
    {
      "field": "Brief_D_Reactiedatum",
      "operator": "!=",
      "value": "Eventtoets_Fn"
    },
    {
      "condition": "or",
      "rules": [
        {
          "field": "Alleen_AO",
          "operator": "=",
          "value": "Parkeerreden"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const conditions = { "and": "$and", "or": "$or" };
const operators = { "=": "$eq", "!=": "$ne", "<": "$lt", "<=": "$lte", ">": "$gt", ">=": "$gte" };

const mapRule = rule => ({
    [operators[rule.operator]]: [ "$"+rule.field, rule.value ]
});

const mapRuleSet = ruleSet => {
    return {
        [conditions[ruleSet.condition]]: ruleSet.rules.map(
            rule => rule.operator ? mapRule(rule) : mapRuleSet(rule)
        )
    }
};

let mongoDbQuery = { $expr: mapRuleSet(q) };
console.log(mongoDbQuery);
```

Result expression can passed either to MongoDB's `find` method

```
db.col.find(mongoDbQuery);
```

or into [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html) pipeline stage:

```
db.col.aggregate([{ $match: mongoDbQuery }]);
```

Comment: thank you very much this works! Could you help to expand this to support a nested array of subdocuments? I would be glad to open another bounty when that becomes available. Related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57259343/convert-query-builder-conditions-to-mongodb-operations-including-nested-array-of

Comment: @pengz I will try to take a look later today, thanks